# How to write into specific mipmap using Metal kernel?

Tags: ios, macos, metal, ipados

When using GLSL, it's easy writing into specific mipmap level.

But I found out it seems missing in Metal shading language.

Well, I might be wrong. Maybe there are some workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. If you are using Metal 2.3 or higher, you can use `void write(Tv color, uint2 coord, uint lod = 0)` or `void write(Tv color, ushort2 coord, ushort lod = 0)` methods on `metal::texture2d`. The problem is, that even with Metal 2.3 `lod` must be 0 on Intel and AMD GPUs.
2. To work around that limitation, you can make an `MTLTexture` view using `newTextureViewWithPixelFormat:textureType:levels:slices:` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1515409-newtextureviewwithpixelformat?language=objc) for the level you want to write.

Comment: Thanks, the second approach looks promising.